# database.bak to database.sql convertion FREE

Tags: sql-server-2008, shared-hosting, plesk

I have a `.bak` file and want to convert it into `.sql` file to restore it on my Windows shared hosting. How can I do this? I can't restore directly using MSSMS because I get the error

> user has no permission to create and restore database

Comment: If this is a  one-off task, get a trial version of SQL Server and install it on your local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, restore your database and generate the scripts for the database and run the script on the hosted server, which creates both the definition and data... (Note, while running the script make sure you generate data and definition)

Comment: is there any tool like phpmyadmin for windows shared hosting.i am unable to access webadmin also :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's most likely because you have no permission to create or restore a database. Ask your shared hosting service to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have MSSQL express at the very least installed on your local computer. Open an instance, create a database named whatever you need that database called. Go on with Task > Restore. Then, you may go back to right click contextual menu of the restored DB and select Copy.